# How to say “Thank you for calling me back” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I've looked around on various translation sites, but can't find a good translation for:

> Thanks for calling me back, or
>
> Thanks for returning my call.

When you've left a message for someone to call you and they (finally) do return your call.

I've been using:

> Merci pour le rappel.

But I'm not sure that's correct — what should I be saying?  Thanks!

Comment: Quand je rappelle qq1, souvent on me dit juste "Merci d'votre appel." Sans référence au fait que j'ai **r**appelé. Sinon, on peut aussi dire: "Merci d'nous avoir recontactés."

Comment: Is it something you say to expect a back call or to thank for a back call you expected? It will have a different translation ?

Comment: Thanks @sinsedrix, i've edited the question to make it clearer - this is specifically when you've asked someone to call you back and what you say to them to thank them for doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use :

> Je vous remercie de (m'avoir rappelé|me rappeler) [si vite]

(First alternation is past tense for the end of the conversation, second alternative is present for the beginning of the conversation. Optional "Si vite" is here to emphasis that a person has called back quickly.)

On the other hand:

> Merci pour le rappel

looks rather like "Thanks for the reminder". If you do not want to emphasis the particular "back calling", you could use :

> Je vous remercie pour votre appel.

It's a traditional sentence you will heard when calling professionals.

Comment: _Je vous remercie de me rappeler_ can make a confusion, because it is the same from than the imperative. I think _Je vous remercie de m'avoir rappelé_ is the best.

Answer (score 5):

Dans le langage courant on dira plutôt:

> Merci de m'avoir rappelé(e).

ou

> Merci d'avoir rappelé.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais « merci de me rappeler » (langue courante).

Comment: No, that's “please call me back later”, but the question was about “thanks for being calling me back right now”.

Comment: I have the same remark to @Mvy's answer. _Je vous remercie de me rappeler_ can sound imperative.

Comment: @Gilles No, that doesn't necessarily means "please call me back later" which would have been, *merci de me rappeler plus tard*. Without *plus tard*, it might be a very common way to thank someone who just call you back.